# Is is possible to style/manipulate the hard-coded tooltips for file upload buttons?

Tags: html, css, button, styles, tooltip

I have made a button to choose a file and then one to upload the file. To the right of the "choose file" button, there is a tooltip saying "No file chosen" which I assume is created by the browser. What I want to know is if there is any way to tell the browser to put this tooltip below the button instead of to the right of the button.

Comment: You could get element selector with devtools and style it

Comment: That doesn't work with file upload buttons. For example, if I add a border, it will add a border around the button and the tooltip but leave the original button inside. So I will end up with a button inside a button.